# How You Style Website that was built for Mobile Devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile

Ok, now most mordern smartphone has 720p or 1080p resolution. That mean even screen size is small like 4 in, we still can see all text, gui (such as email textbox) of the whole website when first time opening it in Galaxy s3.

However, though we can see the very little email textbox in mobile browser, it is too small for us to enter data. So we need to magnify the page and that is very time consuming.

So, here is what i am planning to do but i feel it very strange.

I will create a website like a normal website mydomain.com, but the button  and text on that website is very big.
Ex:
Css

```
.myNormalMobileFont{
    font-size: 500%;
}

.myNormalLargeFont{
    font-size: 700%;
 }
```

The below image shows that no matter where I open my website either in mobile device or in desktop, then it will look like this
[image]

One more thing, when I opened some article page in my mobile I saw they have a mobile web version, but I have  never found these mobile version on the normal Desktop browser?

Where they put their mobile web?

My mobile website can be used as a normal Desktop website but the the buttons and Text will be very big.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to specify the font-size like that as long as you set the correct meta tags.
ex:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

This sets the scale of the viewport.

I suggest you upload your HTMLs to a server and access them from your phone and play around with it there. it's the best way to learn

As for your question regarding where you can find the mobile web, it depends on the site.
1) Sometimes the site is responsive (you can access the site from desktop , resize your browser down and watch it change) ie: https://www.foxtel.com.au/got/login.html
2) But sometimes they have dedicated mobile site, like facebook -> https://m.facebook.com/

Comment: why i open https://m.facebook.com/, the gui is bit different when open in my galaxy s3?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by different? are you accessing http://m.facebook.com on your galaxy as well?

Comment: yes, in webbrowser, there is "Email or Phone" text in front of the textbox, but in the galaxy the text was inside the TextBox

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your issue. for me in the web browser the "email or phone" text is also inside the textbox. what browser are you using? can you show a screenshot?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" /> seem work but the webpage can not be enlarged or reduced as a normal website

Comment: hi there, if you want it to be zoomable, then just change user-scalable=yes. As for your previous question re: the email/phone text, it's just the way some browser renders the HTML differently